# Order statistics of independent NOT identically distributed random variables

Tags: st.statistics, probability-distributions

I want to find the p.d.f of the n-th order statistics from a set of independent, but NOT identically distributed random variables $X_1, \dots, X_n$ (the p.d.f. of the $X_i$'s is at hand)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is Bapat-Beg theorem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bapat%E2%80%93Beg_theorem
Not suprissingly, the permanent shows up. This is why I know it.

Comment: Hmmm. In what way is this Bapat-Beg paper (1989) differ to the result of Vaughan and Venables (1972)?

Vaughan and Venables (1972), Permanent expressions for order statistics densities, JRSS - Series B, 308-310.